# qt emitting a signal across threads by moving the object to

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I'm looking for correct pattern to use it in Qt-based app for async processing.

this is a simplified class which should receive a signals

```
class Receiver : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Receiver(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {    }
public slots:
    void onNewMessage(Message message) {

    // ...
    }
};
```

the creating of the instance of this class is a dynamic (also simplifed, really - an array of the objects for message processing).

```
    Receiver* r;
    // ...
    if (r == nullptr) {
        r = new Receiver{};
        r->moveToThread(new QThread);
        connect(this, &MessageGenerator::messageCompleted, r, &Receiver::onNewMessage);
    }
```

in main function also exists a registration:

```
    qRegisterMetaType<Message> ("Message");
```

the question is why slot is never called?
in case of the removing Thread stuff (moveTOThread) then all works fine , 
but I'd prefer to have a processing in event loops in different threads

Comment: You did not call thread `start`

Comment: thank you ! my inattention :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#QThread):

> Constructs a new QThread to manage a new thread. The parent takes ownership of the QThread. **The thread does not begin executing until start() is called.**

Do you call method [start](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#start), like this?

```
r = new Receiver{};
t = new QThread();
r->moveToThread(t);
connect(this, &MessageGenerator::messageCompleted, r, &Receiver::onNewMessage);
t->start();
```